# Remove duplicate value in gridview rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2013, duplicates

I have seen this question asked and answered before but none of the answers helped me. I want that when I insert a value from the textbox by pressing a button, if that value already exists in the gridview to be removed or not inserted at all.

My code:

```
protected void Buton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = null;

    if (Session["GridData"] == null)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
    }
    else
    {
        dt = Session["GridData"] as DataTable;
    }

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Session["GridData"] = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ITs better you first check value exist or not in the table and than insert it into table.

```
var data = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() 
           where row.Field<string>("Name") == TextBox1.Text
           select   row).ToList();
if(data != null && data.Count > 0)
{
  //insert new row in table 
}
```

or

```
var data = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() 
           select   row).
           FirstODefault(row=>row.Field<string>
                  ("Name") == TextBox1.Text);
if(data != null )
{
  //insert new row in table 
}
```

Comment: I get error  'A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause'. is there something missing?

Comment: @CezaraH - i updated answer i think issue with firstordefault so changed it to list and checking for the count...

Comment: It doesn't like valuetosearch. Even after you edited it, that's where the error occurs.

Comment: @CezaraH - you are getting wrong valuesearch is place holder in you case it will get replaced by TextBox1.Text...because this the text you are searching for

Comment: Thank you, that was it. However, I have one more problem. In visual studio 2013 while debugging the code stops short after pressing the button and an arrow shows up telling me which statement will be executed  next. I can't move this arrow and I was wondering what I could do to get the code to run?

Comment: @CezaraH - can you please provide screen shot of that or any errormessage you are getting...

Comment: @CezaraH - i thin poblem here is you need to replace columntype place holder with your column name in your case i guess it will be Name..but check once and do update

Comment: @CezaraH - wecome...and thank for accepting ...you saved my effort

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for duplicates before adding a row:

```
bool isDuplicate = false;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row["Name"] == TextBox1.Text)
    {
        isDuplicate = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then do your thing if it's not duplicate:

```
if (!isDuplicate)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Session["GridData"] = dt;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but Cezara H also wants to remove the data if it already exists.

Comment: why dont you go for linq or RowFilter  here

Comment: @PranayRana didn't want to miss the syntax since I'm answering from mobile phone :)

Comment: @DominikB if I got it right, he either wants to remove it and then add it again or simply not add it if it already exists which I've done

Comment: I want it not to get inserted a second time. Or have the duplicate value removed. Your code didn't work for that...

Comment: @CezaraH So, if it already exists in the GridView, you want to remove that entry?

Comment: Yeah! Only the duplicate though, not all entries with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

So You Can Check That From Sqlserver side If that value already exist then it should not be inserted i think it's better to check from sql side because it takes less time than checking from code behind

like

`if not exists (select name from table where name=@name) 
begin
insert into table values(name)values(@name) 
end`